# Why can't I inject a service that requires an httpclient an an EF context in a controller that requires the same context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a controller that needs a service so I inject it. The service needs an `HttpClient` so I inject it. They both need the EF context.

I do add the `HttpClient` at Startup for the service. However I have the below error.

In `Startup`:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>();
```

In `MyService` class

```
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
private readonly ReadContext _readContext;
public MyService(HttpClient httpClient, ReadContext readContext)
{
    _httpClient = httpClient;
    _readContext = readContext;
}
```

In my controller:

```
private readonly IMyService _myService;
public MyController(ReadContext ctx, IMyService myService)
{
    _ctx = ctx;
    _myService = myService;
}
```

The error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'MyApp.Backend.ReadContext' from root provider.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type serviceType, IServiceScope scope, IServiceScope rootScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceProviderEngineCallback.OnResolve(Type serviceType, IServiceScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultTypedHttpClientFactory`1.CreateClient(HttpClient httpClient)
```

Not that when the service is injected in a controller that doesn't require `ReadContext`, this works. There seems to be some resolution loop here.

UPDATE

From comments, I understand that `AddHttpClient<T>` creates an instance of `T` with the same lifetime as the `HttpClient` created and managed by aspnet core which is longer than the `DbContext` lifetime which is the lifetime of the actual request. Fair enough. Then how do I inject an `HttpClient` into a transient service?

UPDATE2

As per that [blog](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore) I can inject an instance of `IHttpClientFactory` in `MyService` instead using `services.AddHttpClient();`. Indeed the error goes away. I'll have to do some reading to understand the difference beetween asking the factory for an instance of `HttpClient` or injecting one.

Comment: Error message should be pretty clear. `MyService` is resolved application wide, from the root container, while your DbContext is registered as scoped service and resolved by the scoped container (which is created on every request). If you would inject `MyService` into HttpClient, it would essentially become scoped (and never disposed) unless your application closes, hence creating memory leaks since the DbContext resources (EF cores caching, tracking etc) will never be freed

Comment: I just want `MyController` and `MyService` to be transient while using a "single" `HttpClient` (I let aspnetcore deal with the best way to do so) throughout the app. How should I do? I followed examples from the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

Comment: You're injecting MyService as an HttpClient which is going to be a singleton so it can't depend on a scoped service ie a DbContext and a DbContext should never be a singleton, so you should remove that constructor dependency and instead pass in the dbcontext to the methods on your HttpClient

Comment: I wish the doc mentioned that "linking" `IMyService` and `MyService` through `AddHttpClient` was turning `MyService` into a singleton. A posteriori it's obvious.

Comment: _Then how do I inject an HttpClient into a transient service?_ injecting a static object into a scoped or transient is no problem, they won't be disposed when the scoped/transient object is disposed. But injecting transient/scoped services into a singleton is a problem, because the singleton has lifetime that equals the that one of the application (or AppDomain in traditional .NET Framework - not .NET Core)

Comment: Who said I wanted to inject a transient service into a singleton? That is what I end it up doing hence the error but that was never the intent as you can imagine.

Comment: just curious but.. if you use `MyService` inside the controller and the controller has the `DbContext`, can't you just pass whatever dependency `MyService` needs? If `MyService` is indeed an HttpClient service, that just abstracts some external resource around methods (let's say calling Twitter api), looks strange that it needs dbContext.

Comment: That's not the question 

Answer (score 4):

Register `MyService` as scoped:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
```

And, then just register your `HttpClient` with `MyService`:

```
services.AddHttpClient<MyService>();
```

The way you're doing it now, `MyService` is being created in singleton scope, which makes it impossible to inject scoped dependencies like your context.

Alternatively, you can instead inject `IServiceProvider` and use the service-locator anti-pattern to get your context. It's called an anti-pattern for a reason, so this is not the best way to go about things, but if your service is singleton-scoped, there's no other way:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _services;

    public MyService(HttpClient client, IServiceProvider services)
    {
        _client = client;
        _services = services;
    }
}
```

Then, later:

```
using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ReadContext>();
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Tks it looks like it. I'll try asap. Btw I never do service locator, I don't know why you've mentionned it in the answer.

Comment: It doesn't work. It's like using `AddHttpClient` on any type creates a singleton of that type to be injected.

Comment: It's `IServiceProvider`, not `IServiceCollection` ^^